# C Array probelm showing different result on different platforms

Tags: arrays, c, return, boolean, return-type

Problem statement:-
There are n kids with candies. You are given an integer array candies, where each candies[i] represents the number of candies the ith kid has, and an integer extraCandies, denoting the number of extra candies that you have.

Return a boolean array result of length n, where result[i] is true if, after giving the ith kid all the extraCandies, they will have the greatest number of candies among all the kids, or false otherwise.

Note that multiple kids can have the greatest number of candies.

**Input**: candies = [12,1,12], extraCandies = 10
**Output**: [true,false,true]

for the above problem statement i am writing this below function:-

```
bool* kidsWithCandies(int* candies, int candiesSize, int extraCandies, int* returnSize) {
    *returnSize = candiesSize;
    //  printf("%d ", *returnSize);
    int *tempcandie = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*candiesSize);
    int it1 = 0, it2, temp = 0;
    bool result;
    for (it1;it1 < candiesSize;it1++)
    {
        result = 1;
        tempcandie[it1] = candies[it1] + extraCandies;
        for (it2 = 0;it2 < candiesSize;it2++)
        {
            if (tempcandie[it1] <= candies[it2])
            {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        tempcandie[it1] = result;


    }
    return (bool*)tempcandie;
}
```

if i run this function in my PC in visual studio then i debugger window i can see the tempcandie is holding expected result but if i am running on the one specific coding platform its showing different result what might be the issue

Visual basic debugger window :-
[image]

Platforms output:-

[image]

I am unable to figure out why i am getting difference in output

Comment: `return (bool*)tempcandie;` `int` is not `bool`. If you want to make a `bool` array from an `int` array, allocate a `bool` array, copy values, free the `int` array and return the `bool` array.

Comment: Has it occurred to you that casting an `int *` to a `bool *` might be a problem?  As a general rule, you should avoid attempting pointer casts.  They aren't needed for what you're doing, and you're going to introduce bugs.

Comment: I would suggest to use C compiler instead the C++ one.

Comment: @KamilCuk:Thanks for the input.But even if i am returning int array the value 0 will be considered as false only.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ShujaulHind `sizeof(bool)` might not be the same as `sizeof(int)`. What then?

Comment: Fix your pointer bugs first.  *Then* see if there's still a problem.

Comment: And very often it is https://godbolt.org/z/x13n9x68f

Comment: yes very correct @0___________ i got the problem will try it.Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an array of integers

```
int *tempcandie = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*candiesSize)
```

but return a pointer to the first element of the array as having the type `_Bool` (`bool` is an alias for the type `_Bool`). Objects of the type `int` and of the type `_Bool` can have different sizes. This is the reason of the incorrect output.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "sizeof( int ) = %zu\n", sizeof( int ) );
    printf( "sizeof( _Bool ) = %zu\n", sizeof( _Bool ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
sizeof( int ) = 4
sizeof( _Bool ) = 1
```

Also this function parameter `int* returnSize` is redundant. And the first parameter should have the qualifier `const`.

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool * kidsWithCandies( const int *candies, size_t candiesSize, int extraCandies )
{
    bool *result = NULL;
    
    if ( candiesSize )
    {
        result = malloc( candiesSize * sizeof( bool ) );
    
        if ( result )
        {
            size_t max = 0;
        
            for ( size_t i = 1; i < candiesSize; i++ )
            {
                if ( candies[max] < candies[i] ) max = i;
            }
            
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < candiesSize; i++ )
            {
                result[i] = candies[max] - candies[i] < extraCandies;
            }
        }           
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int candies[] = { 12, 1, 12 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( candies ) / sizeof( *candies );
    
    int extraCandies = 10;
    
    
    bool *result = kidsWithCandies( candies, N, extraCandies );
    
    if ( result )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%s ", result[i] ? "true" : "false" );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    free( result );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true false true
```

Comment: @Shujaul Hind See my appended post.

Comment: Superb that explanation really helped @Valad from Moscow

Answer (score 1):

Never ever use pointers to pun the types.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%zu, %zu\r\n", sizeof(bool), sizeof(int));
}
```

The result is `1,4`.
VS19 result:
[image]

You need to

```
 int *tempcandie = malloc(sizeof(*tempcandie)*candiesSize);
 bool *result = malloc(sizeof(*result)*candiesSize);

 /* ... */

  for(int i = 0; i < candiesize; i++) result[i] = !!tempcandie[i];
```